# Salesforce returning 404 where Postman is not

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, error

I am trying to do a very basic get request to an api.  When I try to execute through Salesforce, I am getting a 404 error.  If hit exact same api through Postman, I am getting through and receiving the json response with no issue.  The site has been added to the list in Salesforce and I already have other code that posts to the API with no issue.  The token is passed through the url and so is the record id I am querying.  Again this works fine in Postman but not in Saleforce, and I'm copying and pasting to ensure no typos.  Here is the code snippet below.  What am I forgetting?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
req.setEndpoint('url here');
req.setMethod('GET');
res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

And response:

> 12:45:38:250 CALLOUT_RESPONSE [9]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Not Found, StatusCode=404]

Comment: URL incorrect? 404 would indicate URL not found

Comment: Headers? Is there any headers in postman? like application/json etc?

Comment: Bah, nvm this was figured out.  I was being given the wrong parameters so it was trying to pull all the records from the table instead of the one I was trying to pass in the parameter.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: dcoder - post an answer please so this question doesn't show up as unanswered within the community

Answer (score -2):

This kind of issues happen that the endpoint may not exposed to make a call from Cloud/Internet.  Please check with Service provider that you can make call from Cloud/internet.